# I am trying to recover a failed posting, just disappeared on Andriod

Tags: applications

On my Galaxy Edge 6, I shared a post from Twitter to LinkedIn. The post stopped at 98% and when I checked the phone again it wasn't posted and it had just vanished. How do I recover the post?

Answer (score 0):

If you go chrome at the top push the red dot and go to Hester.And you can clear up to a weeks worth of data .Just hit clear data and its gone.Form the history of the phone

Comment: And uou2can get